# How can i solve java version problem for solr

Tags: service, solr, installation

I am a noobie for Apachee Solr (version 8.3) and have trying to start solr service on windows.
We install jdk 8 and added java home variable. but still having below error.
Also tried with jdk 13 burt had same error.

'""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java" -version 2>&1 | findstr "version""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

ı thought there is a problem with the solr.cmd code but couldnt find what it is.

COuld you help me?

The line i am considering below lines has a problem;

:resolve_java_vendor
"%JAVA%" -version 2>&1 | findstr /i "IBM J9" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 ( set "JAVA_VENDOR=Oracle" ) else ( set "JAVA_VENDOR=IBM J9" )

Comment: Are you using powershell, bash or regular cmd?

Comment: i am using regular cmd with administration permissions.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set SOLR_JAVA_HOME in the solr.in.cmd file.

Go to the solr/bin directory,
open file solr.in.cmd in any editor

Add the below line in the end

```
 set SOLR_JAVA_HOME=<jre path>
```

For example

```
set SOLR_JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Akash, i have added at the end of the file as you said but same error occured.

Comment: REM For a visual indication in the Admin UI of what type of environment this cluster is, configure
REM a -Dsolr.environment property below. Valid values are prod, stage, test, dev, with an optional
REM label or color, e.g. -Dsolr.environment=test,label=Functional+test,color=brown
REM SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.environment=prod"
set SOLR_JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_231"

Comment: Did it work after the above configuration done by you?

Comment: Just a small detail: there's a `REM set SOLR_JAVA_HOME=` at the beginning of the `solr.in.cmd` file. Uncommenting it (remove REM) and providing the path there does the job. Linux users need to do the same in `solr.in.sh`.